# Can I say: "He took a savory bite" to describe how he acted when he bit the hamburger

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Can I say: "He took a savory bite" to describe how he acted when he bit the hamburger.

I say no teacher says yes. Have I lost my mind? Help!

He took a savory bite of a cheeseburger.

to me a cheeseburger can be savory but can the action also be savory?
thanks

Comment: A "bite" can describe not only an action, but also the portion of the food that is torn off by the teeth. "A bite" in a sentence like "He took a bite of his hamburger" can refer to "the portion of the hamburger that entered his mouth." This portion of the hamburger could be described using any adjective commonly applied to food, like "savory."

Comment: What does a "savory" bite look like?  I can imagine a "large" bite, a "tentative" bite, an "exploratory" bite but not a "savory" bite.  Maybe you can ask the teacher what that savory bite looks like?

Comment: ann, I interpreted your second sentence as *I say no teacher says "yes,"*  but @Kristina interpreted as *I say "no;" teacher says "yes."* I now think she's right, but maybe you could clarify?

Comment: Question is: Is the biting a savory activity, or is the bite of burger a savory thing? Instead of a scoop of ice cream I could taste an ice-cold spoon of ice cream. The ice cream is very cold, so the bit is cold, too.

Comment: Wasn't that a tasty treat to set before the king? The treat was tasty, the hamburger was savory, and the bite of hamburger was savory -- a savory bite. The biting was not savory.

Comment: @sumelic I agree in principle, mostly because PG Wodehouse had no aversion to such statements. But I can't see it working every time with as much aplomb: *?He took a hot bite of his hamburger.*

Comment: He took a refreshing bath.

Comment: Clarification: The object of the assignment was to utilize our script as a tool to provide subtle direction without overtly saying, "Actor: take a big bite and make love to it."  The kid's script originally was written like this:  He takes a bite out of his burger. The teacher changed it to : He takes a savory bite out of his burger.  I took pause. The word just did not sit right. Certainly, because we are being graded specifically on word usage. I just don't think you can take a savory bite.  Everyone laughed at me, mimed the action and tried to get me to understand what savory means. HELP!

Comment: So, the survey says?

Comment: clare - thank you for referencing PG Wodehouse!  I just added this website to my favorites.   Kristina I love your piquant phrase - now I'm hungry.

Comment: The sentence might be technically correct, but savory just seems to be in a non-opportune location.  It's the burger that's savory.  The bite (portion) of the burger will be savory.  "Took a bite" refers to the action of biting more than the action of putting a portion in your mouth (which can be accomplished without tearing the food with your teeth).  So savory seems to describe the action of tearing with your teeth rather than the burger.  A clearer sentence would be "He bit into a savory burger."

Answer (score 1):

If "bite" refers to a certain quantity of food as opposed to the action, then the bite could indeed be "savory".